# Integrate Video file (.mp4) in docx/doc

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, docx4j, aspose.words

I want to integrate video files in docx or doc document means I need to play video inside docx file.

So Can you please provide me lists of Open source or Enterprise java API for this video integration in docx file.

Thanks In Advance... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an mp4 as an OLE object with the Docx4j Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Can I play this video inside docx file ?

Comment: You can click to activate it; typically it will play using eg Windows Media Player.   To see what it would be like, I'd suggest you add an mp4 in Word then click on it.  The experience would be similar.

Comment: Hello Jason, I need functionality like this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnQuWNAYWIE.